# Did Rey really think that she should literally reach out in training?

Tags: star-wars

It seems a little different than what you’d think Rey would be like...

Comment: Rey is naive and untrained. Luke expected she'd do it, hence the reed, it seems like a common mistake among recruits that he probably worked out when he started his temple.

Comment: We won't know what Rey *thought* until the script or the novelisations become available.

Comment: Did you see the film in English? I watched it with subtitles in another language in which there is no equivalent to the vague "reach out" (they actually translated it as "extend your hand", believe it or not). In English, to my mind, extending your hand when told to "reach out" makes perfect sense.

Comment: @terdon In the English version I believe he says reach out and then reach out with your feelings. Extend your hand kind of makes that whole bit pointless...

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot yes, that's precisely my point. I saw it in English (and am a native English speaker), but since I saw it with non-English—and bad—subtitles, I thought the OP might have seen it dubbed. "Reach out" can be interpreted as "reach out *physically*" perfectly easily in English, so it doesn't seem strange to me that Rey would do so.

Answer (score 3):

Well she did reach out with her hand and seemed genuinely surprised about "the Force" touching her hand and even more surprised when Luke smacked her with the reed. So I'd say yes she did.

As for why she did.

- She's naive
- Her only experience with it has been what she has managed to teach herself
- She's untrained

It would seem to be a common mistake amongst learning Jedi, or at least the ones Luke taught at his temple. Otherwise there would have been no reason for him to know to bring the reed outside with him.

Lastly, extending one's hand when you've been told to "reach out" is an extremely common usage of the phrase. It's an easy mistake to make especially when you're not entirely sure what the thing you are being taught about is.

> Luke: Amazing every word in that sentence is wrong.